# Calculating points on a circle that is projected onto the Earth

Tags: c++, geometry, geospatial, geo

I am working with osgEarth, and I am trying to draw lines jutting out from a single point to a circle. 
At first, I attempted to do the following (where m_x_start_lon and m_y_start_lat are some arbitrary starting points):

```
    double x_lon = 0.0f;
    double y_lat = 0.0f;
    if (!GetPointFromScreen(args, x_lon, y_lat)) return true;

    m_stop_x_lon = x_lon;
    m_stop_y_lat = y_lat;

    double x_dist = abs(m_stop_x_lon - m_start_x_lon);
    double y_dist = abs(m_stop_y_lat - m_start_y_lat);

        m_radius = sqrtf(x_dist * x_dist + y_dist * y_dist);

    std::vector<double> x_points(m_slices);
    std::vector<double> y_points(m_slices);

    //m_slices = 30, which is the number of lines to represent the circle
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < m_slices; ++i)
    {
        double new_x = m_start_x_lon + m_radius * cos(i);
        double new_y = m_start_y_lat + m_radius * sin(i);

        x_points.at(i) = new_x;
        y_points.at(i) = new_y;
    }
```

However, this only sort-of worked. The only conclusion I can come to is that working with latitude and longitude somehow skews the results. [image: Please see the attached picture.]

The radius is ~190 meters long horizontally, and ~340 meters long vertically. I am aware of squishing that happens when you are further away from the poles, but I wouldn't think it'd be this extreme until after it exceeds at least a some kilometers in length. And even then, the radius horizontally and vertically should match up.

So, what must I do to get the correct lon,lat coordinates for the edge of my circle?

Comment: I don't have the time to write a usable answer, but you have to consider that for a circle with a radius of more than a few kilometers, on any point outside the tropics, it *will* be skewed because longitudinal lines intersect at the poles. You need to either project your circle onto a spheroid or project your coordinate system from the geoid you're using back into 3D space before you compute the circle, if you want to avoid the squishing.

Comment: Oh, I am aware of the squishing issue. It's bitten me several times. 
However, I don't think that is a problem. I should add the distance to my original post, but the radius horizontally is ~190 meters, vertically it's about 340 meters (when they should both be the same). I wouldn't think that the squishing would be this extreme

Answer (score 2):

This javascript code (sorry no C++) chooses a random bearing and draws a point at a specific distance from a given starting point in that direction.

```
function pointAtDistance(inputCoords, distance) {
    const result = {}
    const coords = toRadians(inputCoords)
    const sinLat =  Math.sin(coords.latitude)
    const cosLat =  Math.cos(coords.latitude)

    const bearing = Math.random() * TWO_PI
    const theta = distance/EARTH_RADIUS
    const sinBearing = Math.sin(bearing)
    const cosBearing =  Math.cos(bearing)
    const sinTheta = Math.sin(theta)
    const cosTheta =    Math.cos(theta)

    result.latitude = Math.asin(sinLat*cosTheta+cosLat*sinTheta*cosBearing);
    result.longitude = coords.longitude + 
    Math.atan2( sinBearing*sinTheta*cosLat, cosTheta-sinLat*Math.sin(result.latitude )
        );
    result.longitude = ((result.longitude+THREE_PI)%TWO_PI)-Math.PI

    return toDegrees(result)
}
```

inputCoords is an object with {latitude: n, longitude: m}

[Please see the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hoolymama/56wzdtax/) where you'll find the missing bits like the constant values and utility functions.

EARTH_RADIUS is in meters so therefore you specify distance in meters

The result longitude is clamped to the range -180 -> +180 degrees

If you want the points regularly distributed around the circle, rip out the random bearing part and pass in numbers between 0 and TWO_PI

**EDIT:** I should mention that this code is based on algorithms from [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you are computing the m_slices loop, instead of slicing the angle as **(2 * PI / m_slices)**, you are computing **sin()** and **cos()** of i which is from 0 to m_slices.

```
double dAngle = (2 * PI / m_slices); // in radian

for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < m_slices; ++i)
{
    double new_x = m_start_x_lon + m_radius * cos(i * dAngle);
    double new_y = m_start_y_lat + m_radius * sin(i * dAngle);

    x_points.at(i) = new_x;
    y_points.at(i) = new_y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured it out -- I was (foolishly) thinking that a radius calculated with lat,lon would be uniform.
To fix the problem, I instead got the distance in meters from Start to Stop, and used that as my radius to find the correct lat,lon points.